# Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS : apache2 won't start on boot, possibly after apt-get upgrade

Tags: boot, apache2, init.d

I just did a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and rebooted my server, but apache2 didn't auto start. I started it manually with `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start` and it started with no problems.

Before the update (although it's been a while and probably a few updates since the last boot), apache2 would start automatically on boot with no problems.

I have checked that the relevant entries exist in /etc/rc2,3,4,5.d (they do) and run `sudo update-rc.d apache2 enable` which seemed to work fine, but it still doesn't start on boot.

I do not have an encrypted filesystem.

I can't find any useful entries in the apache2 error log or syslog.

I am at a loss as to how to debug further or other things to try.